# Avoid tesseract download the traindata

Tags: javascript, tesseract

I am designing a simple OCR webpage to extract text from the image using Tesseract Library. I see that Tesseract OCR downloads a 9 MB file

> eng.traineddata.gz

very first time it uses the OCR. As my connection is slow this takes a lot of time. Is there a way to avoid Tesseract to download that file.

Any suggestions? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: As much as I know this isn't the default behaviour of the standard version. Are using a wrapper for tesseract? Wouldn't placing the data file into the tessdata directory solving the problem

Comment: @tobltobs Thanks for the response. The javascript version of tesseract downloads a file if used in a HTML Page. I dont think it is a problem of the standard version.